# Why using the same code, Firestore not workin in NodeJS but work in browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

The same source code work into a alone html page:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.19.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.19.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script>

  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "XYZ",
    authDomain: "XYZ.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://XYZ.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "XYZ",
    storageBucket: "XYZ.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "XYZ",
    appId: "XYZ"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  let db =null;
  if(!firebase.apps.length){
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    db = firebase.firestore();
  }

  const id = new Date().getTime();
  const userid = new Date().getTime();
  let docRef = db.collection("alarms").doc("teste"+id);

  docRef.set({ userid: userid  }, { merge: true }).then((id)=>{
    console.log("ID:",id);
  }).catch(
    (err)=>{
      console.error(err);
    }
  );
```

Above, the example I taked from the google tutorial and work fine. But, into side server side, using dependences:

package.json

```
 {
  "name": "appengine-typescript",
  "description": "An example TypeScript app running on Google App Engine.",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "license": "Apache Version 2.0",
  "author": "Google Inc.",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=8.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node -r source-map-support/register index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "async_hooks": "^1.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "ejs": "^2.6.2",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "firebase-admin": "8.6.0",
    "firebase-functions": "3.3.0",
    "jest-cli": "^26.4.2",
    "js-sha1": "^0.6.0",
    "node-cache": "^4.2.1",
    "node-rest-client": "^3.1.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.3.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.16",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
  },      
}
```

Source:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as firebase from "firebase-admin";

 if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "XYZ",
        authDomain: "XYZ.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://XYZ.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "XYZ",
        storageBucket: "XYZ.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "XYZ",
        appId: "XYZ"
      };
      // Initialize Firebase
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig); 
}

const db = firebase.firestore();

const cmpID = "cmpid:" + new Date().getTime();
const userid = "userid" + new Date().getTime();


let docRef = db.collection("alarms").doc(cmpID);

docRef.set({ userid  }, { merge: true }).then((id)=>{
    console.log("ID:",id);
  }).catch(
    (err)=>{
      console.error(err);
    }
  );
```

This case, happens the error below:

```
{ Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.
    at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/mnt/c/Users/gandb/Documents/workspace/vriend/v-alarm/services/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:30:26)
    at Http2CallStream.call.on (/mnt/c/Users/gandb/Documents/workspace/vriend/v-alarm/services/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:96:33)
    at Http2CallStream.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at process.nextTick (/mnt/c/Users/gandb/Documents/workspace/vriend/v-alarm/services/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:100:22)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
  code: 7,
  details: 'Missing or insufficient permissions.',
  metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map {}, options: {} } }
```

My Firestore configuration is:

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow  create,read, write, update, delete: if true;
    }
    }
}
```

Also, I tried :

- Change folder and subfolders project permission to 777
- Using a anonymous tab and the html page example continues working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error, ocorrs this message for many reasons, in this case I dont found documentation in any place, even here in stackoverflow.

The reason that ocorrous when you authentic using wrong credencials, valid but for another project. In my case, I use docker container, so I setup the credencial using enviroment variable like this:

```
ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS wrong-project.json
```

I generate the correct json credential and works well.

Into html works before, because html no need credential to work. But into nodeJS , google firestore sdk require credential.